"pretius" plugin translation make duplicates when use multi language appliaction
I'm using Pretius APEX Context Menu
in this link: https://github.com/bostrowski/Pretius-APEX-Context-Menu
when I started translating the Application, it made duplicates in the original language and didn't appear at all in the secondary language
first language(english)
second language(arabic)
thanks in advance
can any one help me

This is not part of the standard APEX codebase. I suggest you raise this with the Pretius team.

@KoenLostrie Ok Thanks but I thought that maybe someone here faced same problem & can help
